# Duplicate rows in R that satisfy condition

Tags: r, duplicates, row, conditional-statements

I want to map one category to multiple categories in R.

I have a dataframe,

```
Region var1 var2
Texas  XX   XX 
Texas  XX   XX
```

I need to relabel Texas as "Dallas" and "Houston", in order words, "Dallas" and "Houston" will share the same values for var1 and var2.

How do I create a dataframe like this:

```
Region var1 var2 Region2
Texas  XX   XX   Dallas
Texas  XX   XX   Dallas
Texas  XX   XX   Houston
Texas  XX   XX   Houston
```

This should involve some duplication of rows by the condition that Region == Texas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially a `merge` operation if you make a separate table for your new regions:

```
big <- data.frame(Region=rep("Texas",2), Region2=c("Dallas","Houston"))
merge(dat,big)
#  Region var1 var2 Region2
#1  Texas   XX   XX  Dallas
#2  Texas   XX   XX Houston
#3  Texas   XX   XX  Dallas
#4  Texas   XX   XX Houston
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option without `merge` is to `transform` the dataset by creating 'Region2' and replicate the sequence of rows to expand it

```
transform(df1, Region2 = c("Dallas", "Houston"))[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), each = 2), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, assuming you have a dataframe with subregions:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
    Region = c("Texas", "Texas"),
    var1 = c("XX", "XX"),
    var2 = c("XX", "XX")
    )

regions <- data.frame(
    Region = c("Texas", "Texas"),
    Region2 = c("Houston", "Dallas")
    )

df %>% right_join(regions, by = "Region")
  Region var1 var2 Region2
1  Texas   XX   XX Houston
2  Texas   XX   XX Houston
3  Texas   XX   XX  Dallas
4  Texas   XX   XX  Dallas
```